# MySQL Contact multiple right joined rows into one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

If I have this

### users

```
id user

1 john   
2 tom
```

and

### states

```
user_id state

1        MA
1        CA
2        VA
```

How do I get a result set that is:

```
id user states


1 john  MA,CA
2 tom   VA
```

I think it has something to do with group contact, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, `group_concat` is the way to go - you just need to `group by` the `users`' columns:

```
SELECT   u.id, u.user, GROUP_CONCAT(s.state)
FROM     users u
JOIN     states s ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.user
```

Comment: This seems to put all states in one user.